# Not able to pass response to start method in batch class

Tags: apex, batch, compile-error

We are getting response from external system ,whose return type is `List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest>` , 
below code I have tried but its giving error:

> Class testAdvensysBatch must implement the method:
>   System.Iterable
>   Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Below is the code:

```
Global class testAdvensysBatch implements  Iterator<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest>,Database.Batchable<sObject>, database.Stateful {

    global   List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest> VehicleInfo=new List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest>();

    Integer Counter;
    public AccountGenerator(Integer GeneratorLimit) {
        Counter = GeneratorLimit;
    }
    global boolean hasNext() {
        return Counter > 0;
    }
    global Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest next() {

        return new Account(Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest);

    }


    global testAdvensysBatch( List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest> VehicleInfo1){
        VehicleInfo=VehicleInfo1;


    }


    Global  Iterable<list<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest>>   start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        return VehicleInfo;

    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<VEH_Vehicle__c> scope){

    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

---

As per suggested answer, I tried the following-

```
Public  with sharing class testAdvensysBatch implements  Database.Batchable<sObject>, database.Stateful {

public   List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest> VehicleInfo=new List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest>();
public testAdvensysBatch( List<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest> VehicleInfo){
    VehicleInfo=VehicleInfo;
}

public  list<Rfleet_AdvensysRequestSchema_CLS.VehicleRequest> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
 return VehicleInfo;
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<VEH_Vehicle__c> scope){

}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
```

}

> But same issue "Class testAdvensysBatch must implement the method: System.Iterable Database.Batchable.start(Database.BatchableContext)" Please let me know, where I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to implement your own iterator, but more importantly your return type should be `List<MyClass>`, not `Iterable<List<MyClass>>`. You also need to make your implementation batch over this type.

Note also that the `public` access modifier is perfectly sufficient. Do not use the `global` modifier unless you are building a managed package or building Apex REST.

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<MyClass.SubClass>
{
    public List<MyClass.SubClass> start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // return vehicle info
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<MyClass.SubClass> scope)
    {
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I am facing same issue

Comment: @subbareddypeddireddy, its always good to update your question with what you have tried as per the suggested answer. This helps in identifying the issue instead of leaving a comment with `still facing same issue`. :)

Comment: @Rahul, above code I have added what I tried..

Comment: Change the parameter on your batch class and remove the iterator completely.